# How can I convert a varchar field (YYYYMM) to a date (MM/01/YY) in SQL?

Tags: sql, hsqldb, openoffice.org

I'm sure this is quite simple, but I've been stuck on it for some time. How can I convert a varchar field (YYYYMM) to a date (MM/01/YY) in SQL?

Thanks.

Edit: I'm using Open Office Base (HSQL), not MySQL; sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) functions. Something like:

```
select date_format( str_to_date( my_column, '%Y%c' ), '%c/01/%y' ) from my_table
```

Answer (score 4):

try :

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(myDate,'01'),'%Y%m%d') 
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 3):

Use STR_TO_DATE:

From [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

> STR_TO_DATE(str,format)
>
> This is the inverse of the DATE_FORMAT() function. It takes a string str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts.
>
> The date, time, or datetime values contained in str should be given in the format indicated by format. For the specifiers that can be used in format, see the DATE_FORMAT() function description. If str contains an illegal date, time, or datetime value, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL. Starting from MySQL 5.0.3, an illegal value also produces a warning.
>
> Range checking on the parts of date values is as described in Section 11.3.1, “The DATETIME, DATE, and TIMESTAMP Types”. This means, for example, that “zero” dates or dates with part values of 0 are allowed unless the SQL mode is set to disallow such values.
>
> mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('00/00/0000', '%m/%d/%Y');
> -> '0000-00-00'
> mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('04/31/2004', '%m/%d/%Y');
> -> '2004-04-31'

Answer (score 1):

- Get the year:

  ```
  SUBSTRING(field FROM 2 FOR 2)
  ```
- Get the month:

  ```
  SUBSTRING(field FROM -2 FOR 2)
  ```
- Compose the date:

  ```
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING(field FROM -2 FOR 2), '/01/', SUBSTRING(field FROM 2 FOR 2))
  ```

This will convert from `YYYYMM` to `MM/01/YY`.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear: if you're looking for method to convert some value of type *Varchar/Text* to value of type *Date* than solutions are:

1. using **CAST** function

`CAST(LEFT('201205',4)||'-'||SUBSTRING('201205' FROM 5 FOR 6)||'-01' AS DATE)`

1. starting from OpenOffice 3.4 (HSQLDB 2.x) new Oracle-like function **TO_DATE** supposed to be available

`TO_DATE('201205','YYYYMM')`

in addition to the written i can mention that you also can construct a string with ANSI/ISO **'YYYY-MM-DD'** formatted representation of the date,- Base will acknowledge that and succesfully convert it to the Date type if necessary (e.g. *INSERT*ing in Date typed column etc.)

Here is doc's on [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/index.html) and highly recommended [OO Base guide](http://www.pitonyak.org/database/) by Andrew Pitonyak